# Response time of volley before getting response

Tags: java, android, android-volley, progress

I am trying to upload the images and videos using volley by converting them into Base64 (strings).

now the reason is that i want to show the user that how much time it will take to upload this data.

is there any way to get volley response time after hitting the api call and before getting the response. That how much time it will take to response the api call.

i have tried this.

```
private long mRequestStartTime;

public void performRequest()
{
mRequestStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // set the request start 
time just before you send the request.

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, PARAMS, 
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) 
        {
            // calculate the duration in milliseconds
            long totalRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mRequestStartTime;
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
        {
            long totalRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mRequestStartTime;
        }
    });

requestQueue.add(request);
```

}

[from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386249/finding-volley-requests-response-time-android)

but in this way it gave the response time after response.

if someone have the solution kindly share it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe volley doesn't offer such an option out of the box, you need to calculate it yourself.
You will need to change your upload approach so that you can do a streamed upload in order to be able to count the bytes sent .. then your estimated upload time will be something like  `requiredTime = totalBytes * bytesUploadedSoFar / passedTime`

Comment: as i said, you don't get it out of the box, you need to implement it yourself ... so you need to create a stream similar to this one here https://github.com/fatahzull/Android-Volley--Multipart-Request-with-Upload-Progress/blob/master/MultipartRequest.java